# Python - Create and instantiate class

Tags: python, class

I am building a `class` of playlists, which will hold many playlists of the same genre.

```
class playlist(object):
      def __init__(self,name):
         self.name = name
```

I would like to instantiate them passing the user:

```
      def hard_rock(self,user):
         self.user = user
         #query and retrieve data from music API
         #return playlist

      def pop_rock(self,user):
         self.user = user
         #query and retrieve data from music API
         #return playlist

      #and so on
```

create instance:

```
r = playlist('rock')
r.hard_rock('user1')
```

is this a logical way of building and instantiating classes?

Comment: What do you expect this to do?  `pop_rock` and `hard_rock` both do the exact same thing.

Comment: So does `__init__()` :P Edit: nvm, different var

Comment: When an instance is created, it should be fully usable. In your case, it isn't: you have to call another method. You should be initializing those attributes in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: If it's simple and readable then it's pythonic. But you basically have two methods that do the same thing but are called differently. So unless you're adding more functionality there then it's kind of pointless and should probably just have an `add_user` function.

Comment: For example, `hard_rock` should be an *instance* of one `Playlist`. This is basic OOP, nothing Pythonic about it

Comment: @cricket_007 care to answer?

Comment: I don't know what your overall goal is here. Could you [edit] to clarify what you would want to do with your class once it's created?

Comment: @cricket_007 clearer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want playlists and users

```
class Playlist(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.liked_by = list()

    @classmethod
    def get_genre(cls, genre):
        # this relies on no instance of this class
        pass
        # return api data...

class User(object):
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

     def likes_playlist(self, playlist):
         playlist.liked_by.append(self.name)
```

And then, some examples

```
playlists = list()
hard_rock = Playlist('hard_rock')

joe = User('joe')
joe.likes_playlist(hard_rock)

playlists.append(hard_rock)
playlists.append(Playlist('pop_rock'))

country = Playlist.get_genre('country')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be possible if playlists are the core component of your application (very simple example using class inheritance).

```
>>> class playlist:
...     def __init__(self,name, user):
...         self.name = name
...         self.user = user
... 
>>> class hardrock(playlist):
...     def __init__(self,name, user):
...         playlist.__init__(self, name, user)
... 
>>> test = hardrock('my_awesome_hardrock_list', 'my_awesome_username')
>>> print test.name
my_awesome_hardrock_list
>>> print test.user
my_awesome_username
```

You could start using just strings for users and later replace them with real objects and add some kind of relations between playlists and users. See cricket_007's suggestion for some more ideas.