# How do I call upon a certain argument within a function?

Tags: python

So I just started learning python and I thought why not make a text-based game to improve my skills. So in this game I want to make a fighting scene where you have a class( Knight, Rogue, or Wizard) and that class is stored in player_class. Each class has three I would say attributes. Each class has a speed, damage, and health. I want to make it so that if your speed is higher or equal to the enemy you attack first, but if the enemy's speed is higher than the enemy attacks first. So I thought I could do this by just calling player_class = userKnight and then in the fight if player_class(speed) >= enemy_type(espeed) then enemy_type(health) - player_class(damage). This doesn't work and if someone has a better method or can explain how I can implement this better would be awesome!

````
def userRogue(damage,speed,health):
    health = 100;
    damage = 50;
    speed = 150;
    return

def userKnight(damage,speed,health):
    health = 100;
    damage = 100;
    speed = 50;
    return

def userWizard(damage,speed,health):
    health = 100;
    damage = 75;
    speed = 75;
    return

def enemyRat(ehealth, espeed, edamage):
    ehealth = 100;
    edamage = 10;
    espeed = 70;
    return

def enemyDeath():
    if ehealth <= 0:
        print("Enemy is dead!")
    return

def playerDeath():
    if health <= 0:
        print("You have died!")
    return

user_name = input("What is your name: ")

print("1:)Rogue")
print("2:)Knight")
print("3:)Wizard")

player_class_select = int(input("Choose your class: "))

player_class = 0
enemy_type = 0

if player_class_select == 1:
    print("You chose Rogue!")
    player_class = userRogue

elif player_class_select == 2:
    print("You chose Knight!")
    player_class = userKnight

elif player_class_select == 3:
    print("You chose Wizard!")
    player_class = userWizard

else:
    print("That is not a choice!")


print("Time for your first battle...")
print("A enemy has appeared!")

enemy_type = enemyRat

if player_class(speed) >= enemy_type(espeed):
    enemy_type(ehealth) - player_class(damage)
    enemyDeath()
elif player_class(speed) < enemy_type(espeed):
    player_class(health) - enemy_type(edamage);
    playerDeath()
    ```
````

Comment: There are numerous problems with this code. I suggest working through the tutorial before trying to debug your code further. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Your `user` methods are useless. They declare local variables and immediately discard them. Try declaring them as globals first.

Comment: You're using functions in an awkward way that won't work out as you want. Functions need to return data that the caller needs. It would make more sense though to have an actual `class`, and set the attributes of the class to match that of the different player "classes".

Comment: I think you unintentionallye made your classes to be functions, instead of actual classes. For defining classes, you have to use the `class` keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Create and instantiate class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40594920/1092820)

Comment: Are you trying to learn more about data types or classes? Your issues are because of your user functions that aren't doing what you expect to but theres two main ways to solve it depending on which answer to my question.. Regardless, don't use globals without understanding them.

Comment: You can assign a function in that way and it does work, your error must be somewhere else. (I.e. foo = function;  foo(x); does work as you would expect)

Comment: Your code doesn't define any classes nor reference the attributes of any instances of them — so I agree you need to become more familiar with Python and OOP before writing your game.

Answer (score 2):

You should make one parent class for your characters as seen here:

```
class Player:
  def __init__(self, name, damage, speed, health):
    self.name = name 
    self.damage = damage
    self.speed = speed
    self.health = health

  def __str__(self):
    return 'Name: {} | Damage: {} | Speed: {} | Health: {}'.format(self.name, self.damage, self.speed, self.health)

rogue = Player('Rogue', 100, 50, 150) # Setting attributes to the parent class
knight = Player('Knight', 100, 100, 50) # name, damage, speed, health
wizard = Player('Wizard', 100, 75, 75)
rat = Player('Rat', 100, 10, 70)

print(rogue)
print(knight)
print(wizard)
print(rat)
```

This creates your players and attributes:

```
Name: Rogue | Damage: 100 | Speed: 50 | Health: 150
Name: Knight | Damage: 100 | Speed: 100 | Health: 50
Name: Wizard | Damage: 100 | Speed: 75 | Health: 75
Name: Rat | Damage: 100 | Speed: 10 | Health: 70
```

Using this information is relatively easy to compare it to another value of another player/enemy:

```
if rogue.speed > rat.speed:
do something
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I agree I should get more familiar with python before making this. I was just using this as a way to try to put things together on my own and experiment during school.

Comment: Please consider ticking the answer if you feel it is correct